# Running multiple geo $near queries inside an $or

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to do multiple geo queries like $near or $geoNear inside an $or statement when querying a mongodb database?

I´m always getting the error "exception: $or may not contain 'special' query"

After a bit of googling i found the issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3984 which is closed and marked as "fixed".

For me it still seems that there is an error when running multiple geo queries.
Here´s my testing code:

```
db.entry.find({
    $or: [
        {
            "address.geo": {
                $near: { 
                    $geometry : {
                       type : "Point" ,
                       coordinates : [ 9.7043 , 52.3019 ] },
                    $maxDistance : 50000 
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "address.geo": {
                $near: { 
                    $geometry : {
                       type : "Point" ,
                       coordinates : [ 9.6043 , 52.1019 ] },
                    $maxDistance : 50000 
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}).count();
```

And that´s the result:

```
uncaught exception: count failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: $or may not contain 'special' query",
    "code" : 13291,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: as we´re still in an evaluation phase we are on the newest on - 2.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use $near (or $nearSphere) inside of an $or clause:

> **$or and GeoSpatial Queries**
>
> Changed in version 2.6.
>
> $or supports geospatial clauses with the following exception for the
>   near clause (near clause includes $nearSphere and $near). $or cannot
>   contain a near clause with any other clause.

You can however use other geospatial clauses within $or, so if you can refactor your query to use a different geospatial operator you would be able to use $or.

Comment: ok. but which one?! i have to query for entries within a given radius from a center position. the only one i can figure out is "$geoWithin". i´m getting the same error for this one... :(

Comment: ok. i got it to work with $geoWithin and $center. unfortunately for $circle i can provide a parameter called "radius". this radius unit is not in meters or kilometers but in the units from the coordinates system. so a radius with value "1" gives me a way bigger radius than expected. but that should now be easy going, since we´re using no spheres for our geo infos. thank you ;)

Comment: No problem. The unit of measure is in radians, so if you want to convert from miles or kilometers you can follow the directions here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/

Comment: @JohnPetrone I want to compare my location with a startLocation, endLocation and a list of waypoints. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `$near` (or `$nearSphere`) inside of an `$or` clause and `$and` clause. Execute two queries for get data